# System miscalculates reputation when determining if reputation cap is reached?

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

The system has counted me as reaching the cap on reputation for the day when I have not, in fact, done so.

Here's a screen shot:

[image: picture for posterity]

Unless I am just hitting a complete blind spot on this, I have 190 from stuff which counts towards the cap (upvotes) and 30 for stuff which doesn't (acceptances). That does total 220 as shown, but it does not mean that I've hit the cap.

Yet the system is still counting me as reaching the cap. I know this because it just told me so which is why I noticed.

Comment: I don't see the system acting as though you've hit the rep cap: there are no upvotes there without rep gain.

Comment: @JosephWright It gave me a badge which it said depended on hitting it. Or does that just depend on getting 200, even if the 200 comes from acceptances as well? I don't remember exactly what it said so maybe I am just confused?

Comment: See Werner's as-usual excellent answer. Some things are about getting 200 rep by any means, others are about getting capped.

Comment: @JosephWright Actually, the answer isn't what's helpful. It is the comment on it which is helpful. Thanks ;).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your reputation log (sorted by post) for that day (2015-07-05) looks like this:

[image]

All "events" show an accompanying reputation change (+10 for upvotes to answers, +15 for acceptance of answers). If you had reached the daily reputation cap for the day (+200 from non-excluded reputation gains), you would notice something like this (taken from [egreg's reputation profile](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg?tab=reputation) for the same day):

[image]

Note the blank space for an upvote to [an answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/253802/5764). *This* implies that the reputation cap for the day has been reached.

---

However, 200-rep-per-day badges (like [Mortarboard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/badges/41/mortarboard), [Epic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/badges/42/epic) and [Legendary](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/badges/43/legendary)) makes no consideration as to what gave you 200 reputation on any day; there is no distinction between reputation due to voting, accepting, suggested edits or bounties.

Indeed, this was the notification you saw after having [received the silver Epic badge](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/badges/42/epic?userid=39222).

Comment: 200-rep-per-day badges (like [Mortarboard](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/badges/41/mortarboard), [Epic](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/badges/42/epic) and [Legendary](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/badges/43/legendary)) does not care what gave you 200 reputation on any day though.

Comment: Can you put your comment in the answer so I can accept it? That's what was confusing me. The system gave me some badge and I didn't realise that the 200 it was going on about included acceptances. [Of course you'd only see a blank if you would otherwise have *exceeded* the cap for the day - not if you'd only reached it.] But anyway, I knew I *hadn't* reached the cap. But the badge thing made me think it had *counted* me as doing so.

Comment: @cfr: Done, with some mention of the notification you received.

Comment: Thanks. I find the system really confusing sometimes ;).